# Wordpress and .htaccess – pretty permalinks and undefined function

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I read several similar topics on stack, but none of answers did the job, so:

I started using Wordpress and created my first theme. I have placed WP in `localhost/first-wp/` and in `localhost/first-wp/wp-content/themes/first-theme/` I have several files, like *index.php*, *login.php* or *register.php*.

Now, I want to access this files through pretty permalink, for example `localhost/first-wp/login` or `localhost/first-wp/register`.

I created *.htaccess* file in `localhost/first-wp/` and placed there this content:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /first-wp/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^login? /first-wp/wp-content/themes/first-theme/login.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^register? /first-wp/wp-content/themes/first-theme/register.php [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /first-wp/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

But the problem is, when I enter for example `localhost/first-wp/login` I'm getting error: `Call undefined function 'my_simple_func()' in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/first-wp/wp-content/themes/first-theme/login.php`.
This function is placed, of course, in *functions.php* in my theme directory.

How do I solve this problem, to enter pretty permalinks and not getting this error?
Thanks for all advices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are duplicating your directorys with RewriteBase.

Try:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /first-wp/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^login? wp-content/themes/first-theme/login.php [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^register? wp-content/themes/first-theme/register.php [QSA,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```